# Email sending using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to send the mail from PowerShell.

```
$EmailFrom = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
$EmailTo = "xxxxx@gmail.com"
$Subject = "Subject"
$Body = "Body"
$filenameAndPath = "C:\Desktop\EE.txt"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"

$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)

$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($filenameAndPath)
$SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)

$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxx@gmail.com", "password"); 
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

When I run this code I get the following exception:

```
Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."
At line:13 char:1
+ $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException
```

How can I make `$SMTPClient.Send()` work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Is `Send-MailMessage` not an option for you?

You could do the following:

```
$EmailFrom = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
$EmailTo = "xxxxx@gmail.com"
$Subject = "Subject"
$Body = "Body"
$filenameAndPath = "C:\Desktop\EE.txt"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"

Send-MailMessage -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $Subject -body $Body -Attachments $filenameAndPath -SmtpServer $SMTPServer
```

Comment: Thanks for response.
i am new to powershell.
As you said i proceeded further but no luck i received the below error.  Please help me.

Comment: Thanks for response.
As you said i proceeded further but no luck i received the below error.  Please help me.
Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. r76sm7795282pfb.69 - gsmtp
At line:8 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $Subject -bod ...
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

Answer (score 0):

Would this example work?

```
##############################################################################
$From = "YourEmail@gmail.com"
$To = "AnotherEmail@YourDomain.com"
$Cc = "YourBoss@YourDomain.com"
$Attachment = "C:\temp\Some random file.txt"
$Subject = "Email Subject"
$Body = "Insert body text here"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject `
-Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl `
-Credential (Get-Credential) -Attachments $Attachment
##############################################################################
```

Notice that it asks for credentials and also specifies to UseSSL.
It's from https://www.pdq.com/blog/powershell-send-mailmessage-gmail/

Answer (score 0):

I have found when using Powershell script to send emails in Gmail you have to first log into the Gmail account and allow the location/IP address of the sending PC to send Emails. From the same PC running the script log into Gmail and there should be a security email. Click allow and then test.